# Ingres SQL illegal pattern match and illegal escape sequence, unexpected results

Tags: sql, database, escaping, ingres

I am querying a database that uses Ingres 10.2. I cannot seem to get any of my pattern matching code to work as I expect it to.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE variable_name IN ('XaKDG', 'XaKDH')
```

returns both XaKDG and XaKDH as expected.

However, when trying this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE variable_name LIKE 'XaKD\[GH\]' escape  '\'
```

I get the following errors:

> ERROR '22025' 1315172
> Illegal pattern match specified
> Illegal ESCAPE sequence.

I am baffled, as the user guide states the following:

"To match any string starting with 0 through 4, followed by an uppercase letter, then a [, any two characters and a final ]:"

```
name like '\[01234\]\[A-Z\][__]' escape '\'
```

As far as I can tell, my query should be correct. I also tried without the escape characters at all, and with double escape characters. These didn't produce any errors, but also did not return anything.

I appreciate any help.

The User guide is here: https://supportactian.secure.force.com/help/servlet/fileField?id=0BEf3000000PLPf

Comment: Ingres 10.2 is the dbms unless I misunderstand the meaning of the term

Comment: Per the documentation, can you verify your DBMS actually supports that ESCAPE clause? I assume so, but this is more of a sanity check. See: ```The iidbcapabilities catalog contains information about the capabilities
provided by the Enterprise Access product or Ingres DBMS. ... The cap_capability column in the iidbcapabilities catalog contains one or more
of the following values: ESCAPE - Contains Y if DBMS supports the
ESCAPE clause of the LIKE predicate
in the WHERE clause of search
statements. Contains N if ESCAPE is
not supported.``` The row below that explains what the escape char is

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that part of the documentation.  Yes, the escape clause is supported.
# cap_capability cap_value
18 ESCAPE Y

Comment: I can't lay my hands on a 10.2 dbms server (support having expired for 10.2 now) but the syntax is correct, I tried the following in 11.1 and got the expected output: declare global temporary table session.x(name varchar(50)) on commit preserve rows with norecovery; insert into session.x values('XaKDG'),('XaKDH'),('YyYYY'); select * from session.x where name like 'XaKD\[GH\]' escape '\';

Comment: What client are you using? Its not impossible that the client is doing something with your escape characters and producing unexpected results. Where as if you're using the ingres terminal we can probably rule that out.